# sanitization for wysiwyg editor

Tags: php, security, mysqli

i am using a wysiwyg editor , if i use strict sanitizing rules then all the tags are getting stripped , i just want to prevent sql injection , how can i do it

currently i am just using code something like

```
$something= $_POST['content'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO database (content) VALUES($something)";
```

(not using any sanitization)

and directly adding it into database ... how can i validize the input without my tags from wysiwyg editor getting stripped

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use editor , sanitization text input via HTML Purifier Class : http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: its overkill for simple user input sanitisation